# Sqoop --escaped-by --optionally-enclosed-by

Tags: oracle, import, sqoop

i have a requirement to import the data into .csv file with comma(,) as a delimiter .

i am using below sqoop options .

--optionally-enclosed-by '\"'
--escaped-by '\\'

below is the input data and output data i want .

input **"foo** output i want **""foo**
but i am getting below
input **"foo** output **"foo**

another example :

input **foo"** output i want **foo""**
but i am getting below
input **foo"** output **foo"**

how can i achieve the desired output

Answer (score 3):

Refer [SqoopGuide 7.2.11. Large Objects](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_large_objects) for a better understanding of --enclosed-by,--escaped-by and --optionally-enclosed-by with examples.

Based on the question, below are the details understood.

```
--fields-terminated-by ,    Since you need a file with a comma as the delimiter.
--optionally-enclosed-by '\"'  This will enclose only the fields whose data contains delimiter comma , in them.
--escaped-by \\   Used to escape the enclosing characters(double quotes in this case) if they are present in the data field which requires enclosing.
```

Example:

Input: Suppose if the data in source table is like below with the respective columns. For representation, I used pipe(|) as the delimiter.

```
Some string, with a comma.|1|2|3...
Another "string with quotes"|4|5|6...
```

Output: sqoop import --fields-terminated-by , --enclosed-by '\"' --escaped-by \ ...

```
"Some string, with a comma.","1","2","3"...
"Another \"string with quotes\"","4","5","6"...
```

Explanation: All fields are terminated by comma and all fields are enclosed by double-quotes. If there is any field with double-quotes in the data then those quotes will be escaped by a backslash() as in the second line.

Output: sqoop import --fields-terminated-by , --optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --escaped-by \ ...

```
"Some string, with a comma.",1,2,3...
"Another \"string with quotes\"",4,5,6...
```

Explanation: All fields are terminated by comma and only fields contacting the comma in the data are enclosed by double-quotes. If there is any field with double-quotes in the data then those quotes will be escaped by a backslash() as in the second line and even this column will also be enclosed as in the second line.

For your scenario:

Input: Suppose if the data in the source table is like below with the respective columns. For representation, I used pipe(|) as the delimiter.

```
"foo|bar"|1|2
foo"|3|4|"bar
```

Possible Output: sqoop import --fields-terminated-by , --enclosed-by '\"' --escaped-by \ ...

```
"\"foo","bar\"","1","2"
"foo\"","3","4","\"bar"
```

Possible Output: sqoop import --fields-terminated-by , --optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --escaped-by \ ...

```
"\"foo","bar\"",1,2
"foo\"",3,4,"\"bar"
```